# Simple if statement in bash doesn't work 2

Tags: bash

I have this code in bash

```
#!/bin/bash       
echo "php version"
read NAME
if ["$NAME" = "5.6"] 
then
    sudo a2dismod php7.1
    sudo a2enmod php5.6
    sudo service apache2 restart
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
else
    sudo a2dismod php5.6
    sudo a2enmod php7.1
    sudo service apache2 restart
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
fi
```

But problem is that if don`t work as I expect, because when I run

```
./enphp.sh
```

I got this error:

```
/home/irebega/bash/enphp.sh: line 4: [5.6: command not found
```

Comment: `if [ "$NAME" = "5.6" ]`

Comment: oh, spaces) Thx a lot

Comment: Probably better to add a semicolon after the bracket